# Java sockets with thread execution

Tags: java, sockets, multithreading

i have coded a socket listener that should listen on port 80 and 81 and when data arrive on these ports execute operations on these data. I want this listener to concurrently listen on both these ports and hav coded in the following way.

```
 import java.net.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.text.DateFormat;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

    public class MultipleSocketServer implements Runnable {

     private int a;
  private ServerSocket connection;
  private String TimeStamp;
  private int ID;
public static void main(String[] args){

       // System.out.print("ip");
     // String gh="12345";
      //System.out.println(gh.substring(1,3));
  int port = 80;
  int port1 = 81;
  int count = 0;
  double a=234.52121;

   //System.out.println(bf3.toString());
    try{

      ServerSocket socket1 = new ServerSocket(port);
      ServerSocket socket2=new ServerSocket(port1);
      System.out.println("MultipleSocketServer Initialized");
      Runnable runnable = new MultipleSocketServer(socket1, ++count);
        Runnable run = new MultipleSocketServer(socket2, ++count);
        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(run);
      while (true) {
        //Socket connection = socket1.accept();

        thread.start();
        thread1.start();
      }
    }

    catch (Exception e) {}
  }
MultipleSocketServer(ServerSocket s, int i) {
  this.connection = s;
  this.ID = i;
}
public void run() {
    while(true){


    try {
        Socket incoming=connection.accept();


            BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(incoming.getInputStream());
            int character;
     while((character = is.read())!=-1) {
    .
    .
    do the input data handling here
    .
    .

    }
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
    }
    }
}
```

But for some reason this does not seem to show the threaded/conncurrent behaviour.
I am testing this code using Hyperterminal, and every time i disconnect from hyperterminal, the program execution stops and "Socket is closed" exception is raised.

Any pointers would be of great help

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're starting threads in an endless loop.

```
while (true) {
  //Socket connection = socket1.accept();
  thread.start();
  thread1.start();
}
```

I think though, that this is handled (ignored) in

```
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

However, I suspect that the problem you describe is in in the handling code you didn't include. One pretty obvious idea: you don't call `connection.close()` instead of `incoming.close()`, do you?

Comment: @sfussenegger: Thank you, you're a lifesaver. And at the same time, i cant believe what a dork I've been. :D
Result of multiple changes to code structure, i guess :)